# Android Development Eclipse Luna EE Errors

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand these errors. Can anyone help ?

```
[2015-03-20 17:04:07 - RobsHelloWorld] /Users/frederickdavidpina/Documents/workspace/RobsHelloWorld/res/values/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-03-20 17:04:07 - RobsHelloWorld] 
[2015-03-20 17:04:07 - RobsHelloWorld] /Users/frederickdavidpina/Documents/workspace/RobsHelloWorld/res/values-v11/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-03-20 17:04:07 - RobsHelloWorld] 
[2015-03-20 17:04:07 - RobsHelloWorld] /Users/frederickdavidpina/Documents/workspace/RobsHelloWorld/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-03-20 17:04:07 - RobsHelloWorld]
```

Comment: welcome @Mr., you should provide more details to get relevant answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you downloaded the Android Support Library from SDK manager?
If not then go to sdk manager Then check the `Android Support Library`
and install the package. After installation restart your eclipse. It should work.